# php json array sort group sum

Tags: php, json, sorting, grouping

Is there a way to group, sort and sum an array.
I have tried everything - with sort, array_unique, foreach and so on.
The following data is notionell.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [clientName] => Audi
        [model] => A6 
        [cost] => 40.000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [clientName] => Audi
        [model] => S8
        [cost] => 90.000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [clientName] => VW
        [model] => Golf V
        [cost] => 5.000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [clientName] => VW
        [model] => Golf V
        [cost] => 3.500
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [clientName] => Audi
        [model] => RS6
        [cost] => 120.000
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [clientName] => VW
        [model] => Passat CC
        [cost] => 35.000
    )

)
```

i would like to have an output like this (in html)

```
Audi            total cost: 250.000
A6              40.000
S8              90.000
RS6             120.000

VW              total cost: 43.500
Golf V          8.500
Passat CC       35.000
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help !!

Comment: show here what your tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$totals = [];
$models = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $totals[$row['clientName']] += $row['cost'];
    $models[$row['clientName']][] = $row;
}
```

So now you have an array of totals with the client name as key, and an array of client names with an array of models in it.

```
foreach($models as $client => $cars) {
   echo $client.' total: '.$totals[$client].'<br />';
   foreach($cars as $model) {
      echo $model['model'].' '.$model['cost'].'<br />';
   }
}
```

I haven't tested this so it might need tweaking but hopefully thgat'll work for you! Let me know!

EDIT:

```
<?php

$json = '[{"clientName":"Audi","model":"A6","cost":40000},{"clientName":"Audi","model":"S8","cost":90000},{"clientName":"VW","model":"GolfV","cost":5000},{"clientName":"VW","model":"GolfV","cost":3500},{"clientName":"Audi","model":"RS6","cost":120000},{"clientName":"VW","model":"PassatCC","cost":35000}]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$totals = [];
$makes = [];
$modelTotals = [];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    // Set defaults to suppress notices
    $totals[$row['clientName']] = isset($totals[$row['clientName']]) ? $totals[$row['clientName']] : 0;
    $modelTotals[$row['model']] = isset($modelTotals[$row['model']]) ? $modelTotals[$row['model']] : 0;

    $totals[$row['clientName']] += $row['cost'];
    $makes[$row['clientName']][$row['model']] = $row;
    $modelTotals[$row['model']] += $row['cost'];
}

foreach($makes as $client => $cars) {
   echo $client.' total: '.$totals[$client]."\n";
   foreach($cars as $model) {
      echo $model['model'].' '.$modelTotals[$model['model']]."\n";
   }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Audi total: 250000 
A6 40000 
S8 90000 
RS6 120000 
VW total: 43500 
GolfV 8500 
PassatCC 35000
```

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/kbkng

Comment: Thanks dude - almost perfect. Just the models are not grouped, so that in this example i see golf V twice than together

Comment: can you `json_encode()` the array and paste the string so I can test it on 3v4l?

Comment: you can just try it in php , doesnt matter if its json or not.. its just an array @delboy1978uk https://eval.in/857184 - thank u dude

Comment: I can't be assed editing that `print_r` output to work in my sample, I'm a busy man. Please just encode and paste if you want more help!

Comment: i appreciate your effort @delboy1978uk .. i have updated the link with json https://eval.in/857241

Comment: sorted, have a look

Answer (score 0):

The Commented, Self-Explanatory Snippet below does the Trick. Please note that all Floating Point Values were converted to Integers.

```
<?php

    $arr = [
        [
            'clientName'    => 'Audi',
            'model'         => 'A6',
            'cost'          => 40000,
        ],

        [
            'clientName'    => 'Audi',
            'model'         => 'S8',
            'cost'          => 90000,
        ],

        [
            'clientName'    => 'VW',
            'model'         => 'Golf V',
            'cost'          => 5000,
        ],

        [
            'clientName'    => 'VW',
            'model'         => 'Golf V',
            'cost'          => 3500,
        ],

        [
            'clientName'    => 'Audi',
            'model'         => 'RS6',
            'cost'          => 120000,
        ],

        [
            'clientName'    => 'VW',
            'model'         => 'Passat CC',
            'cost'          =>  35000,
        ],
    ];


    // A VARIABLE TO HOLD ALL GROUPED ENTRIES
    $group      = [];
    // LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY AND BUILD THE GROUPS BASED ON 'clientName' ENTRY
    foreach($arr as $iKey=>$rData){
        $sKey   = $rData['clientName'];

        if(!array_key_exists($sKey, $group)){
            $group[$sKey]           = ['total'=>$rData['cost'], $rData ];
        }else{
            $group[$sKey]['total'] += $rData['cost'];
            $group[$sKey][]         = $rData;
        }
    }

    // RENDER TO REFLECT THE OP's END DATA-STRUCTURE
    $result = "<table>";
    foreach($group as $clName=>$groupData){
        $result .= "<tr style='color'>";
        $result .= "<th>{$clName}</th>";
        $result .= "<th>{$groupData['total']}</th>";
        $result .= "</tr>";
        foreach($groupData as $k=>$v){
            $result .= "<tr>";
            $result .= "<td>{$v['model']}</td>";
            $result .= "<td>{$v['cost']}</td>";
            $result .= "</tr>";
        }
        $result .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    }
    $result .= "</table>";

    var_dump($group);
    echo($result);
```

[QUICK TEST HERE:](https://eval.in/857144)
[image]

**UPDATE**

To add **"Golf V"** to the List, You may have to add one extra nested `if` Conditional Block to the snippet above.... This would mean adding something like this:

```
  <?php

        if($mdlKey == 'Golf V'){
            if(!array_key_exists($mdlKey, $group)){
                $group[$mdlKey]           = ['total'=>$rData['cost'], $rData ];
            }else{
                $group[$mdlKey]['total'] += $rData['cost'];
                $group[$mdlKey][]         = $rData;
            }
        }
```

In the End, your main Looping Construct could look like this:

```
  <?php

    // A VARIABLE TO HOLD ALL GROUPED ENTRIES
    $group      = [];
    // LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY AND BUILD THE GROUPS BASED ON 'clientName' ENTRY
    foreach($arr as $iKey=>$rData){
        $sKey   = $rData['clientName'];
        $mdlKey = $rData['model'];

        if(!array_key_exists($sKey, $group)){
            $group[$sKey]           = ['total'=>$rData['cost'], $rData ];
        }else{
            $group[$sKey]['total'] += $rData['cost'];
            $group[$sKey][]         = $rData;
        }

        if($mdlKey == 'Golf V'){
            if(!array_key_exists($mdlKey, $group)){
                $group[$mdlKey]           = ['total'=>$rData['cost'], $rData ];
            }else{
                $group[$mdlKey]['total'] += $rData['cost'];
                $group[$mdlKey][]         = $rData;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this ist a nice work. Thank you very much. But is there a way to list "Golf V" and the sum in one row ? like GolfV - 8500 ?? @Poiz

Comment: @dr.oetker  Try if the updated solution works for you.... Cheers and Good-Luck ;-)

Comment: thanks for your effort. But i think we misunderstood each other. The model should be listet in the td where vw is and not in a extra table. And still listed twice... But i think i can work with it and try to get it now on my own. Thank you very much